# csvreader adds extra empty row at the bottom of the table

Tags: csvsimple

I want to create a `xltabular` table by loading the content of a CSV file, which is imported by way of `csvreader`. At the end of the table, an extra empty undesired row is shown. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here below my MWE, thank you for your help.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
keyword|type|range of value|m.u.|description
version|uint32\_t| current  version |-| version of  the  FGFS  structure  in  use  (check  net_fdm.hxx  for  its  value).  It  is  not  necessary  to  assign  a  value  to  this  field,  it  is  detected  automatically. 
padding|uint32\_t|none|-| not  used.  Never  assign  a  value. 
longitude|double|[-180,+180]|rad| geodetic  longitude 
latitude|double|[-90,+90]|rad| geodetic  latitude 
altitude|double|-|m| altitude  above  sea  level 
agl|float|-|m| altitude  above  ground  level 
phi|float|[-180,+180]|rad| roll  angle 
theta|float|[-180,+180]|rad| pitch  angle 
psi|float|[-180,+180]|rad| true  heading 
alpha|float|-|rad| angle  of  attack 
beta|float|-|rad| side  slip  angle 
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|l|l|r|l|X|}\toprule
  \csvreader[
      late after line=\\\midrule,
      late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
      respect underscore = true,
      separator = pipe,]
      {\jobname.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv }
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I think it is caused by

> `late after last line=\\\bottomrule,`

as this command starts a new line after the last csv-entry, without new data to fill it.

I solved this problem by using

```
late after last line=\ ,
```

as it only adds an empty space instead of the new line. I used the longtable environment, but i guess the bottom line can by created with xltabular too.

I know this may not be a proper solution, but it worked for me.